# How to use Brail as a stand-alone general purpose templating engine (like NVelocity)?

Tags: code-generation, template-engine, brail

I've been using NVelocity as a stand-alone templating engine in my text file generator. The problem with NVelocity is that the macros are quite shaky; pretty much all errors I get are from faulty macro implementation.

It would be cool if I could just use some other templating engine, such as Brail. That way I would just write functions that output strings.

What's the best way of embedding Brail engine? I would like to just pass it a string containing the template (not reading from disk), and I would like to minimize the number of external dependencies.

**EDIT:** I found the answer myself. [Take a look at this source file from Castle](http://svn.castleproject.org:8080/svn/castle/trunk/MonoRail/Castle.MonoRail.Views.Brail/StandaloneBooViewEngine.cs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [nHaml](http://andrewpeters.net/2007/12/19/introducing-nhaml-an-aspnet-mvc-view-engine/) or [Spark](http://dev.dejardin.org/) as they both support full [standalone](http://andrewpeters.net/2008/04/19/standalone-nhaml/) or [direct](http://dev.dejardin.org/trac/spark/browser/trunk/src/Samples/DirectUsage) usage

They both support standard c# functions that return strings etc

Spark is real HTML, nHaml is DRY HTML

Both very cool!

Comment: Yes, but I care more for the ability of defining simple macros within the template. What kind of language do they support?

Comment: ? .Net c#, you can't get much easier than that

Comment: I mean the template engine has its own language for logic. For instance WebForms would use c#/vb, Brail uses Boo, NVelocity uses velocimacros, etc.
I want to be able to have some simple code within the view.

Comment: Usually best to keep all code out of the view and put it into your controller/presenter

Also best to use one language for a project, this avoids coding confusions especialy for "the next guy!"

Comment: I had trouble with the links for nHaml and Spark:  These seem to work:  Spark: http://sparkviewengine.com/  nHaml: http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/