# Sending emails from code - Frameworks

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

I'm currently writing a web application that sends out various emails with dynamic textual content using the SmtpClient and MailMessage .net API classes - I just find I'm drowning in a sea of stringbuilders.

Are there any email/templateing frameworks to help with this sort of thing? That also work in **medium trust**.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a template framework like [NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/)

EDIT: It seems like the SourceForge NVelocity is dead, but the guys of [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/others/nvelocity/index.html) had forked it. As I use Velocity for Java and NVelocity is the port for .NET I recommend it ;)

Comment: last version 2003? Still up to scratch?

Comment: Here the answer, hehe - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699094/is-the-nvelocity-project-dead-are-there-alternatives

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [stringtemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/)

[NVelocity](http://nvelocity.sourceforge.net/) is what we used in my last project

Answer (score 0):

Try [T4](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/T4TextTemplateTransformationToolkitCodeGenerationBestKeptVisualStudioSecret.aspx) if you do not want to introduce another dependency to your project.

Comment: T4 is a templating framework, which answers your question "Are there any email/templateing frameworks to help with this sort of thing?"

Answer (score 0):

I don't use a template framework, but I do use HTML pages as my email templates.  I then put in variables like "<#UserName#>" into the HTML that get replaced in code.  This allows me to easily edit the body of the email without having to touch the code.... Unless I want to add a few more new varibles.  The other benefit to using standard HTML pages as my templates, is the ability for non-programmers to design/manage the email body layout...

Comment: What if he wants to include a loop in his 'template'?

Answer (score 0):

In Some special cases when i can't use a tool and must write mine and as you said want to make loops through the template.

I create a normal aspx page in my project and put there all the controls i need "server controls, databinding controls"

And then call this page using a silent call:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("MyASPXPage.aspx");
request.Method = "GET";
response = request.GetResponse();
reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
result = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

after that you will have the result string variable contain all the page which you can send as a mail.

I used this once and it worked nice.

But sure if you found a tool to help you in that, this will be better.